# Retirar campos null de um model que recebe uma lista

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Preciso retirar todos os campos null, que vem de uma lista de `Phones`, tentei fazer da seguinte forma, mas infelizmente não funcionou:

```
model.Phones = model.Phones.Where(x => x.Phone != null && x.Phone != "")
                                          .Distinct()
                                          .ToList();
```

recebi o seguinte erro:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode parecer uma pergunta idiota, mas o erro de NullReference ocorreu utilizando esses dados da imagem?

Comment: Não exatamente, essa imagem fiz com um exemplo, mas também geram o erro. Aonde gerou o erro invés de estar `{Konbase.Areas.Admin....}` estava `null`

Comment: No caso essa lista de telefones está em memoria ou você traz ela direto do banco de dados?

Comment: Na verdade ela vem de um `form`, eu gero dinamicamente campos de `Telefones` com `BeginCollection`, assim o usuário pode digitar quantos campos de telefone quiser, dessa forma deixando inputs `null` caso ele não preencha todos.

Comment: O comando está correto mesmo. O erro provavelmente ocorre por a `model` ou a `model.Phones` estar nula. Tente validar se está `null` antes de usar o comando.

Comment: Seu problema então está no envio do form, ele devia enviar "apenas" os telefones que possuem valores. Mas é possível dar um delete para poder remover os valores, algo assim: "model.Phones.Remove(x => string.IsnullOrEmpty(x.Phone))". Com isso deve resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver,

Caso alguém precise da resposta fiz da seguinte forma:

`model.Phones = model.Phones.Where(x => x != null && x.Phone != null).Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma, verifique se sua `lista` de fones possui algum valor, e depois execute a logica.

```
if(model.Phones.Count > 0)
 //coloque aqui sua logica
```

Você pode verificar se seus telefones estão preenchidos também, antes de adiciona-los na sua lista, segue exemplo:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(telefone))
  //adiciona telefone a lista
```

Comment: Na verdade, o meu problema é que como os campos que o usuário envia são inputs dinamicos, exemplo ele pode ter apenas 1 input de telefone ou 30, isso depende de usuário e ele pode criar o input e enviar ele vazio, isso que gera meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo como isto

`model.Phones.RemoveAll(item => item == null);`

Troque o `item` conforme sua necessidade...

Coloquei no fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVn50U

Answer (score -1):

Se você recebeu a Exceção `NullReferenceException`, tente o código abaixo, às vezes o campo `Phones` pode estar null.

```
if(model?.Phones?.Count > 0)
{
 model.Phones = model.Phones.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Phone)).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: acabei de tentar isso, mas continou recebendo o mexmo erro

Comment: Tenta novamente, mudei a confição IF